# push my local files to my server with git without pulling/cloning files from server

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab

This might be confusing but I will try to explain it as simple as possible :D

ok I have some files on my server and it's being used right now and I made some changes on them.

now I want to make it possible for my developer which is using another machine to push from his local to the server.

I added a git repo on my server to make it possible to push from local to the server directly by adding a post-receive file in hooks with this code in it

`git --work-tree=/root/server/resources --git-dir=/root/git/server.git checkout master -f`

but the problem now is my files on my sytem are not synced with the server and I want to be able to push from my local to the server (my developer too) so I need to sync the git from server with my local and my developer local **without cloning again** because project size is big (2gb)

I can push the server files on github or gitlab but problem is I have to push again from my local which is not possible for me

I need to somehow sync the duplicate files on local machine with server and just clone the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your issue correctly, you can first run git status on local to check for the current situation between your local and remote server. To start syncing, you can run `git fetch --prune` to get all the changes from the server repo and clean the old references on local while syncing up the remote references on the server with local ([check out git-scm doc on the prune option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune)).

After that you need to sync your local branch with the remote one, so you should reset your local branch to align with the remote one.

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This resets your local branch with the remote branch ('master' in this case)

**Warning: this will remove any changes that weren't committed and commits that weren't pushed from local**

you can also clean untracked and ignored files with `git clean -f -d` and `git clean -f -d -x` respectively. just make sure to execute a dry-run (with '-n' flag) to see what would happen before actually running the clean up.

**Note:** In case of any mess-up, you can use git reflog to recover any deleted commits, branches or undo rebase or merge mistakes.

Comment: problem is when I do "git status" it checks my local and it tells me that I'm not tracking any of my files which is correct. it doesn't check it with the github repo and when I try to fetch it starts downloading all the files (7.5k file 1.4 gb)

Comment: on my local I first do "git init" and then add the repo by "git remote add" , that's what I'm doing. not sure if it's correct or not

Comment: Do you have the same files on your local as on the remote server? @AlirezaBehnamnik

Comment: Yes. that's the problem . most of the files are the sime like 80% of it but it still download all of them. I pushed the files from server to github repo

Comment: @AlirezaBehnamnik run `git remote add origin [github url]` then run `git fetch origin`. then check if you can merge and push according to the differences between local and remote. Let me know if that works!

Comment: @alighaddr it starts downloading all files when I do fetch. exactly 7494 files starts downloading with 40kb speed and that's the reason I can't fetch all the files